# InfoPath RichText gets lost when assigned from one field to another

Tags: infopath

I created a client based InfoPath 2007 form, that contains two RichText fields (A, B). I put a rule on A that fires everytime A is changed and simply assigns B with the value of A:

```
B = .
```

So I expect both to show the same value after I changed A, but they don't: B shows only the plain text version of the contents in A. Why?

Answer (score 1):

This is being done through eval()  function

Please see attached to

- [writing values from a multiple-selection list box to another control](http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/t/14658.aspx) discussion

XSN templates with solutions